# In LWC, Is there a anyway you can let users to directly use their phone or desktop to capture photo/video?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I'm curious If you can make a function that users can use their phone or devices to use a camera to capture their photo data into the org.

I've done enough research for accessing user media, and from my experience with HTML, I know you can use MediaDeviceInfo for most of the features I want. But as some of you know there is Locker API in Salesforce, and it is not supporting MediaDeviceInfo yet in Salesforce.

I'm thinking of implementing Aura Component to use the media function, but Salesforce is eventually trying not to support Aura anymore.

For now, I've come across the final options.

1. There is no function similar to the MediaDeviceInfo.
2. Use saved media instead of live media capture.
3. Use Aura (have to learn)

Any idea is welcomed. Any help deciding my decision or idea to breakthrough this problems.

Comment: Have you heard of [nimbus](https://github.com/salesforce/nimbus)? See the developer preview live [here](https://youtu.be/j4g-aaKc2aM?t=1156).

Comment: Thanks for the share, I'll look into this. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe I'm not following what you want, but just using [file upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) allows the user to use their camera to snap a photo to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_intro), you should be able to use `navigator.mediaDevices`. Of course, this will only work in a Lightning Web Component (not Aura), but this should provide the flexibility you're looking for without learning Aura.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks you are helping me this time agian

Comment: @IanLee I haven't personally tried this, but the LWS Distortion Viewer says nothing about not being able to use it, so it should be safe to use.

Comment: This worked for me, was able to record audio in a LWC using the navigator.mediaDevices API